# How can I do batch deletes millions on entities using DatastoreIO and Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to use Dataflow to delete many millions of Datastore entities and the pace is extremely slow (5 entities/s). I am hoping you can explain to me the pattern I should follow to allow that to scale up to a reasonable pace. Just adding more workers did not help.

The Datastore Admin console has the ability to delete all entities of a specific kind but it fails a lot and takes me a week or more to delete 40 million entities. Dataflow ought to be able to help me delete millions of entities that match only certain query parameters as well.

I'm guessing that some type of batching strategy should be employed (where I create a mutation with 1000 deletes in it for example) but its not obvious to me how I would go about that. DatastoreIO gives me just one entity at a time to work with. Pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Below is my current slow solution.

```
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
DatastoreIO.Source source = DatastoreIO.source()
    .withDataset(options.getDataset())
    .withQuery(getInstrumentQuery(options))
    .withNamespace(options.getNamespace());
p.apply("ReadLeafDataFromDatastore", Read.from(source))
 .apply("DeleteRecords", ParDo.of(new DeleteInstrument(options.getDataset())));
p.run();

static class DeleteInstrument extends DoFn<Entity, Integer> {
 String dataset;
  DeleteInstrument(String dataset) {
    this.dataset = dataset;
  }
  @Override
  public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
    DatastoreV1.Mutation.Builder mutation = DatastoreV1.Mutation.newBuilder();
    mutation.addDelete(c.element().getKey());
    final DatastoreV1.CommitRequest.Builder request = DatastoreV1.CommitRequest.newBuilder();
    request.setMutation(mutation);
    request.setMode(DatastoreV1.CommitRequest.Mode.NON_TRANSACTIONAL);
    try {
      DatastoreOptions.Builder dbo = new DatastoreOptions.Builder();
      dbo.dataset(dataset);
      dbo.credential(getCredential());
      Datastore db = DatastoreFactory.get().create(dbo.build());
      db.commit(request.build());
      c.output(1);
      count++;
      if(count%100 == 0) {
        LOG.info(count+"");
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      c.output(0);
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct way of deleting entities using the current version of DatastoreIO. This version of DatastoreIO is going to be deprecated in favor of a new version (v1beta3) in the next Dataflow release. We think there is a good use case for providing a delete utility (either through an example or PTransform), but still work in progress.

For now you can batch your deletes, instead of deleting one at a time:

```
  public static class DeleteEntityFn extends DoFn<Entity, Void> {
    // Datastore max batch limit
    private static final int DATASTORE_BATCH_UPDATE_LIMIT = 500;
    private Datastore db;
    private List<Key> keyList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void startBundle(Context c) throws Exception {
      // Initialize Datastore Client 
      // db = ...  
    }

    @Override
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
      keyList.add(c.element().getKey());
      if (keyList.size() >= DATASTORE_BATCH_UPDATE_LIMIT) {
        flush();
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void finishBundle(Context c) throws Exception {
      if (keyList.size() > 0) {
        flush();
      }
    }

    private void flush() throws Exception {
      // Make one delete request instead of one for each element.
      CommitRequest request =
          CommitRequest.newBuilder()
              .setMode(CommitRequest.Mode.NON_TRANSACTIONAL)
              .setMutation(Mutation.newBuilder().addAllDelete(keyList).build())
              .build();
      db.commit(request);
      keyList.clear();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try that out and see how that works. Can I speed up the deletes just by adding more workers (--numWorkers=20)? It is unclear to me how Dataflow assigns the provisioned workers. It does not help to read keys faster if the backlog is the deleting.

Comment: I can confirm that adding more runners actually slows down the deletes. "Too much contention" errors ends of cutting the entities per second by about 75%.